# What timber to use for formwork or shuttering concrete base

Tags: concrete, timber-framing, shutters

What type of timber would you use to construct the formwork (shuttering). There seems to be 4 different types that I could use.

1. Planed
2. Sawn Untreated
3. Sawn Treated
4. Carcassing

My particular project is for a garage slab that will have a 100 mm sub-base with 100 mm of concrete ontop e.g. The image below shows the sub-base and the proposed formwork.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pine, sawn untreated.

Pine - most typical for structure civil works, doesn't need to have some better grades or something. It's just for formwork after all...

Sawn untreated - concrete doesn't care, so You shouldn't also. These planks will serve as another formwork or to feed some furnace.